# Group datetime by an interval of minutes

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to group my list using linq by an interval of 30 minutes.

Let’s say we have this list:

- X called at 10:00 AM
- Y called at 10:10 AM
- Y called at 10:20 AM
- Y called at 10:35 AM
- X called at 10:40 AM
- Y called at 10:45 AM

What i need is to group these items in a 30 minutes frame and by user, like so:

- X called at 10:00 AM
- Y called 3 times between 10:10 AM and 10:35 AM
- X called at 10:40 AM
- Y called at 10:45 AM

Here's what i'm using with Linq:

```
myList
.GroupBy(i => i.caller, (k, g) => g
.GroupBy(i => (long)new TimeSpan(Convert.ToDateTime(i.date).Ticks - g.Min(e => Convert.ToDateTime(e.date)).Ticks).TotalMinutes / 30)
.Select(g => new
{
  count = g.Count(),
  obj = g
}));
```

I need the result in one list, but instead im getting the result in nested lists, which needs multiple foreach to extract.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't group 10:20, 10:35, and 10:45 together, or 10:10 and 10:20 together and 10:35 and 10:45 in a separate group?

Comment: @juharr I think it is plain the buckets begin with the earliest time for each caller.

Comment: @juharr there is already a record on 10:10 but that's 35 mins away from the last call for user Y. So i needed to get the difference between the first and last call to be <= 30 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `SelectMany` which will unwind one level of grouping:

```
var ans = myList
            .GroupBy(c => c.caller, (caller, cg) => new { Key = caller, MinDateTime = cg.Min(c => c.date), Calls = cg })
            .SelectMany(cg => cg.Calls.GroupBy(c => (int)(c.date - cg.MinDateTime).TotalMinutes / 30))
            .OrderBy(cg => cg.Min(c => c.date))
            .ToList();
```

Note: The `GroupBy` return selects the `Min` as a minor efficiency improvement so you don't constantly re-find the minimum `DateTime` for each group per call.

Note 2: The `(int)` conversion creates the buckets - otherwise, `.TotalMinutes` returns a `double` and the division by 30 just gives you a (unique) fractional answer and you get no grouping into buckets.

By modifying the initial code (again for minor efficiency), you can reformat the answer to match your textual result:

```
var ans = myList
            .GroupBy(c => c.caller, (caller, cg) => new { Key = caller, MinDateTime = cg.Min(c => c.date), Calls = cg })
            .SelectMany(cg => cg.Calls.GroupBy(c => (int)(c.date - cg.MinDateTime).TotalMinutes / 30), (bucket, cg) => new { FirstCall = cg.MinBy(c => c.date), Calls = cg })
            .OrderBy(fcc => fcc.FirstCall.date)
            .ToList();

var ans2 = ans.Select(fcc => new { Caller = fcc.FirstCall.caller, FirstCallDateTime = fcc.FirstCall.date, LastCallDateTime = fcc.Calls.Max(c => c.date), Count = fcc.Calls.Count() })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: It worked! The only thing i changed is that the c.date and cg.MinDateTime are both of type DateTime in myList. So i added a Convert.ToDateTime() for both and worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @CalvinRaad I don't understand - if they are already of type `DateTime` why did you need to add a `Convert.ToDateTime`?

Comment: i meant they should be of type Datetime - they are originally of type string

Comment: @CalvinRaad Ah! I didn't see the convert in your original code :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping by a `DateTime`, try grouping by a key derived from the date.

```cs
string GetTimeBucketId(DateTime time) {
    return $"${time.Year}-{time.Month}-{time.Day}T{time.Hour}-{time.Minute % 30}";
}

myList
  .GroupBy(i => GetTimeBucketId(i.caller.date))
  .Select(g => { Count = g.Count(), Key = g.Key });
```

Comment: That would group minutes of 1 and 31 together.  I think you meant to use `/ 30` instad.  However that would not group 10:35 with 10:10 as the cutoff would be at 10:30.